# Is it possible to conditionally render src script within VueJs for the paypal smart button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to implement a paypal smart button within VueJs, however my payment processing application have to handle multiple currencies. The currency the paypal accepts is defined within index.html script file which you cannot dynamically change within VueJS. However is it possible to substitute this approach of something built in within VueJs when the smart button/s gets renders. Meaning that is it possible to dynamically change the **&currency=XXX** or the marchant code parameter depending on condition?

*I am unwilling to use vue-paypal-checkout solution as its deprecated regarding endpoints and what response info can you retrieve.*

Furthermore I have tried similar solutions to this below but encounter 'paypal' not defined error due to rendering.

```
let ckeditor = document.createElement('script');    ckeditor.setAttribute('src',"//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full/ckeditor.js");
document.head.appendChild(ckeditor);
```

From *https://medium.com/@lassiuosukainen/how-to-include-a-script-tag-on-a-vue-component-fe10940af9e8*

Below you can see my smart button render function.
The render button function lives within a function as it gets executed when a page gets mounted. This page in my scenario is a child.

```
 createPayPalOrderFor10() {

            var selectedIdOfService = this.serviceIdSelected
            var enteredNumberOfCustomer = this.telephoneNumberEntered

            paypal.Buttons({
                createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                    return actions.order.create({
                        purchase_units: [{
                            amount: {
                                value: '10.00',
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                },
                onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {

                            AXIOS({
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: 'api/order/',
                                data: {
                                    serviceId: selectedIdOfService,
                                    telephoneNumber: enteredNumberOfCustomer,
                                    amount: details.purchase_units[0].amount.value,
                                    customerPayPalId: data.payerID,
                                    paymentCurrency: details.purchase_units[0].amount.currency_code,
                                    payPalCaptureTime: details.create_time,
                                    transactionId: details.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id,
                                    orderNumber: data.orderID
                                },
                            })
                                .then(response => {
                                    console.log(response.data)


                                })

                    }

                    );
                }

            }).render('#paypal-button-container-10');



        },
```

Any help suggestions or further references will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Why not just add `currency_code` to the `amount` object? and you can add `payee: { merchant_id: <merchant_id> }` for a dynamic merchant.

Comment: tried that as well complains about that it has to be predefined within the script tag

Comment: You can set the default currency to `USD` and then set the `currency_code` within the `amount` object specifically and it will b used.

Comment: as mentioned before they have to be defined within the script tag in some sort, by manually providing the currency_code it complains. By adding merchant id it complains about that it was expecting the field to be "undefined". Any other suggestions?